# How do I determine if VBScript is running in RDP Console?

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I have an MSI installer that fails if it is running over remote desktop.  (Unless it is run with the /admin or /console option so that it gets session 0)

I want to use a VBScript custom action to determine if I am running as Session 0.  I've learned that I can use two WMI calls to determine this:

- GetCurrentProcessID()
- ProcessIdToSessionId()

However, I have no clue how to call these things in VBScript.  And ideas?

Comment: I'm not even sure these are possible to easily call directly from VBScript.. I say fix the bug in the installer and not the symptom. there isn't much of a reason that an installer should fail in a remote desktop session.

Comment: I'm using the Chained MSI feature.  Apparently, this is a known bug with this feature.

Comment: Earlz and durilai, I'm following your advice after all and getting rid of the Chained MSI feature.  

With Windows 2008 Server, you can't get Session 0 with RDP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
connection = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%SESSIONNAME%")
WScript.Echo connection
```

"Console" = local machine

"RDP-Tcp#**0**" = Remote Desktop (**0** can be any number)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a much easier solution:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
sessionName=oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%SESSIONNAME%")
if ( sessionName = "Console" ) then 

    Msgbox "You are running directly!"
else

    MsgBox "You are in a Remote Session!"

end if
```

Comment: I thought of doing it this way, but I actually need to know the session id.  If the user launches mstsc with the /console or /admin option, they get session 0 and the installation succeeds.

Comment: I think you should understand that using /console will effectively overtake the console session.  If someone is already logged in they will be prompted to let you take control unless that user is the same account that you are connecting as with the /console option.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278845  Either way, the session will appear as Console.